# Добавление постов и их просмотр под конкретным пользователем yii2

Tags: yii2

Имеются 2 таблицы в БД "user" и "requests". Есть поле user_id в таблице "requests"  оно связано с полем "id" в таблице "user". В поле user_id руками установлено значение по умолчанию (id конкретного пользователя). Если задать поле значение null, добавленных постов не видно.
Как правильно добавить связь между таблицами, чтобы поле user_id заполнялось автоматически при добавлении поста id-шником авторизованного пользователя? А у пользователя admin, были права на просмотр всех постов добавленных пользователями.

Таблица "user":

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`auth_key` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`password_hash` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`password_reset_token` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`status` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10',
`created_at` DATE NOT NULL,
`updated_at` DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE INDEX `username` (`username`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`) USING BTREE,
UNIQUE INDEX `password_reset_token` (`password_reset_token`) USING BTREE
```

)

Таблица "requests":

```
CREATE TABLE `requests` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '19',
`theme` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
`service` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
`category` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
`priority` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
`text` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
`filename` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
`created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `requests_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

)

Связь с User в модели Requests:

```
public function getUser (): ActiveQuery
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class(),['id'=>'user_id']);
}
```

Контроллер:

```
 public function actionIndex()

{
    $searchModel = new RequestsSearch();
    $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id; // ID пользователя
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


    return $this->render('index',
        [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

    ]);
}
```

Модель RequestsSearch:

```
 $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;;
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'user_id' => $user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для автоматического заполнения user_id можно добавить behaviors в модель, как тут показано - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior

Но нужно будет изменить наименование поля и убрать то, которое будет задаваться при обновление 'createdByAttribute' => 'user_id', 'updatedByAttribute' => false,

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все работает!